# Open Partial View in Modal Popup using Knockout.js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have partial View AssetList loaded with viewmodel usning knockout.js

```
 <td> 
    <div class="left CursorP ellipsis" style="float: left;" data-bind="text: 
     Name, attr: { 'title': Name },click:$root.eventHandlers.ViewDetail"></div>


</td>
<td data-bind="text: Description"></td>
<td data-bind="text: Source"></td>
<td data-bind="text: CapturedBy"></td>
<td data-bind="text: Status"></td>
<td data-bind="text: LastAccessedBy"></td>
```

In .JS File I need to open the _AssetDetail partial view on click of Name Link

this.ViewDetail = function () {

```
       self.SelectedAssetTodelete.removeAll();
        self.SelectedAssetTodelete.push(this);
       window.location =  "#assetId=" + this.Id; --This is opening the Partial view correctly but in the same tab
     };
```

The Link [assetDetailPage] is     Secure/Content/Catalog/Detail?assetId=" + this.Id

Instead of the same window[window.location] , How we can open Modal Popup using this link inside ViewDetail Function above?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `iframe` tag to load outside content.

```
<iframe width="300" height="300"
  data-bind="attr: { src: 'Secure/Content/Catalog/Detail?assetId=' + Id }"></iframe>
```

I don't know your model structure, you may need to replace `Id` with `Id()` or `$parent.Id()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using jquery

```
<iframe width="300" height="300" id="model"
    data-bind="
        attr: { src: $root.LoadModel(Id) }
"></iframe>


self.LoadModel = function(id){
    var location = 'Secure/Content/Catalog/Detail?assetId='+id
    $('#model').load(location)
    return location
}
```

Comment: This will probably add the partial page in Iframe in the same row / column of the table.I need to open the Page in Modal Popup window when you click on name link in the first column of the Table.

Answer (score 0):

- I Want open the Popup with the same Secure/Content/Catalog/Detail?assetId=' + Id on Name link click on Grid; not load the IFrame.